# Get parameters from command line in Python

Tags: python

I wonder how good programmers get command line parameters in Python? What if there are a lot of parameters?

```
def main():
    type = None if len(sys.argv) == 1 else sys.argv[1]
    date = None if len(sys.argv) != 3 else sys.argv[2]
```

Comment: Did you try `sys.argc`?

Comment: Have you looked at the [argparse](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/argparse.htm) module that comes with Python 2.7 onwards?

Comment: @Smac89 There isn't a `sys.argc` :)

Comment: You don't assign 40,000 command line arguments to 40,000 variables.  There are things called lists.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out [argparse](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html), it's replacing optparse.